# raise an event when an object appears using HLSL and XNA

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl, kinect-sdk

I've written an HLSL code to make transparency of player using depth view of Kinect on the background image. this is my HLSL code :

```
sampler stream : register(s0);
sampler back : register(s1);
sampler middle : register(s2);
sampler character : register(s3);


float4 DepthToRGB(float2 texCoord : TEXCOORD0) : COLOR0
{
    float4 color = tex2D(stream, texCoord);
    float4 backColor =  tex2D(back, texCoord);
    float4 middleColor = tex2D(middle, texCoord);
    float4 characterColor = tex2D(character, texCoord);

    // convert from [0,1] to [0,15]
    color *= 15.01f;

    // unpack the individual components into a single int
    int4 iColor = (int4)color;
    int depthV = iColor.w * 4096 + iColor.x * 256 + iColor.y * 16 + iColor.z;

    // player mask is in the lower 8 bits
    int playerId = depthV % 8;

    if(playerId == 0)
    {
        //Not yet recognized
        return backColor * middleColor;
    }
    else
    {
        return characterColor;
    }
}

technique KinectDepth
{
    pass KinectDepth
    {
        PixelShader = compile ps_2_0 DepthToRGB();
    }
}
```

and this is my Draw method in C#:

```
public void Draw(GameTime gameTime, SpriteBatch SharedSpriteBatch)
    {
        // If we don't have a depth target, exit
        if (this.depthTexture == null) return;

        if (this.needToRedrawBackBuffer)
        {
            // Set the backbuffer and clear
            this.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(this.backBuffer);
            this.GraphicsDevice.Clear(ClearOptions.Target, Color.Black, 1.0f, 0);

            this.depthTexture.SetData<short>(this.depthData);


            GraphicsDevice.Textures[0] = this.depthTexture;
            GraphicsDevice.Textures[1] = back;
            GraphicsDevice.Textures[2] = middle;
            GraphicsDevice.Textures[3] = character;

            // Draw the depth image
            SharedSpriteBatch.Begin(SpriteSortMode.Immediate, null, null, null, null, this.kinectDepthVisualizer);
            SharedSpriteBatch.Draw(this.depthTexture, Vector2.Zero, Color.White);
            SharedSpriteBatch.End();

            // Reset the render target and prepare to draw scaled image
            this.GraphicsDevice.SetRenderTarget(null);

            // No need to re-render the back buffer until we get new data
            this.needToRedrawBackBuffer = false;
        }

        // Draw scaled image
        SharedSpriteBatch.Begin();
        SharedSpriteBatch.Draw(
            this.backBuffer,
            new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, (int)Size.X, (int)Size.Y),
            null,
            Color.White);
        SharedSpriteBatch.End();
    }
```

back and character are my foreground and background images.
middle is used to put object between foreground and background image.
and when I move my body on the object, the object appears.

I wanna ask about how can I raise an event or something after 2 second when the object appears ?

Thanks